# AngularJS displaying HTML Code character in variable

Tags: html, angularjs, string

I would like to put an HTML Code into a AngularJS variable and display it. In my example I am trying to displaying a checkmark character. https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/check-mark/

The below code does work correctly:

```
<label>&#10003;</label>
```

But this does not work, because the CheckMark variable is seeing it as an exact string:

```
<label>{{CheckMark}}</label>  

$scope.CheckMark = "&#10003;";
```

I would still like to keep CheckMark a string variable (because sometimes it should just be normal text) but how can I make it display this checkmark correctly?

Comment: The duplicate answers the question in the title, but I'd use a literal checkbox character (or a JavaScript escape) instead of HTML when writing JavaScript.

Comment: @Quentin Would you mind explaining "but I'd use a literal checkbox character"? Would you give me an example of this please

Comment: Example of a literal checkbox character: `✓`